# Angular 2 Drag & Drop interface

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I was looking for a package or module to be able to drag HTML elements and position them anywhere on the screen.

I found 2 packages:

1. https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula
2. https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd

Both are missing 2 of my needs: To be able get the current position on the screen (X & Y), and abbility to drag and drop elements anywhere on the screen.

I know that there is [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).

What I exactly need is the [Android drag and drop](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) just for Angular 2.

Anyone can point me to any module that can work with Angular 2 in order to make Drag & Drop interface to be able to drag and drop items everywhere and save the position?

Answer (score 0):

A [plnkr sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/G0Sb1NG0Xeq2R5TDLPMT?p=preview). It is basic and leaves lots of layout issues out but demonstrates what you wanted, note that the Draggable and Movable are separate.

The basic usage is:

```
      <div class="note" draggable movable #m1="movable" (movement)="m1.move($event)">movable note a </div>
```

I saw you asked about rxjs, [**this post**](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) is the best starting point.

=============================================================

dragula is great and works smoothly, but as you said, does not fit your needs.

The DND api is a more elaborate one for elements interaction and enable you to drag one element onto another to implement interaction (think about file upload in most modern web apps). It supports accepting and rejecting of drag (drop targets) and passing data with the dragged element.

A draggable directive is pretty easy to implement in angular2 and should take ~30 lines of code. I implemented one and if you want I can share the outlines of the code in a gist.

The main issue is how to position the items on the screen. To do so you'll need to use position absolute and potentially break your layout structure. Is this something that you find acceptable in your app? The reason I say this is that you become very sensitive to your html structure. If you element is inside a hierarchy of relative/absolute positioning elements, things might not work properly

Comment: I can deal with the poisition issues, but I would love to understands how to work natively with mouse events in Angular 2. Learning from such sample could be great.

Answer (score 0):

Even that post is a little bit old, still, for whoever's looking for a solution for this case, after a lot of searching I found a nice draggable implementation, build completely native for angular 4+ , without access to jquery, so it conforms the Angular approach of not interacting directly with DOM.

https://xieziyu.github.io/angular2-draggable

Easy installation and use, works like a charm, also it provides boundary, swap and snap to grid functionality.

Tried on angular 6 and worked at first try.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19984011)

Comment: @SRack , I understand you about this, but should I get to the source component copy/paste all his work there, to have it here?

Comment: Someone flagged your answer @ABens, and that comment was generated via the review. The reason it's in place is that links often change / fail over time, so the answer should contain enough context to stand alone. More on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), if you like. However, in your case it seems I'm in the minority (click the 'Review' link in the first comment), so it's me in the wrong :)